# Android physical back button error

Tags: android, angular, typescript, navigation, nativescript

When I tap `physical Android Button` I've got the next error:

> Unhandled exception java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan
>   (2..2) ends beyound length 0

Here is my **app.routing.ts**

```
import { LoginComponent } from "./pages/login/login.component";
import { CarwashComponent } from "./pages/carwash/carwash.component";
import { NewOrderComponent } from "./pages/new_order/new-order.component";
import { ProfileComponent } from "./pages/profile/profile.component";
import { OrderDetailComponent } from "./pages/order/order-detail/order-detail.component";

export const routes = [
  { path: "", component: LoginComponent },
  { path: "profile", component: ProfileComponent},
  { path: "carwash", component: CarwashComponent },
  { path: "order-detail/:order_id", component: OrderDetailComponent },
  { path: "new_order", component: NewOrderComponent}
];

export const navigatableComponents = [
  LoginComponent,
  CarwashComponent,
  ProfileComponent,
  OrderDetailComponent,
  NewOrderComponent
];
```

Example of the page:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild, OnChanges } from "@angular/core";
import { CarwashService } from "../../../shared/carwash/carwash.service";
import { OrderService } from "../../../shared/order/order.service";
import { Page } from "ui/page";
import { Color } from "color";
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from "@angular/router";
import { TimePicker } from "ui/time-picker";
import { DatePicker } from "ui/date-picker";
import { StoredData } from "../../../shared/config"
import * as application from "application";

@Component({
    selector: "order-detail",
    providers: [CarwashService, OrderService],
    templateUrl: "pages/order/order-detail/order-detail.html",
    styleUrls: ["pages/order/order-detail/order-detail-common.css", "pages/order/order-detail/order-detail.css"]
})    

export class OrderDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private page: Page,
        private router: Router,
        private carwashService: CarwashService,
        private orderService: OrderService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute){}

    ngOnInit() {... }    
    checkStatus(){...}    
    addOrderTotalName(){...}    

    changeStatus(status){...}    
    closeOrder(){...}    
    cancelOrder(){...}
}
```

What's wrong?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edscz.png)

Comment: What are you trying to do? Provide more code

Comment: I tap on Android Back Button. I expect that I will return to the previous page, but get this error.

Comment: Without more code it is hard to tell what your problem is

Comment: Do I have to handle a standard android back button in code?

Comment: Code of what page can help you understand my error?

Comment: The page on which you press the back button. Does it happen only one page or on every page?

Comment: It happen on every page. I added code of page.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the physical back button will behave as going back to previous page, but I don't know why this happens to you. You can try to define again the function for the back button like this:

```
var application = require("application")
var topmost = require("ui/frame").topmost;

var activity = application.android.startActivity ||
        application.android.foregroundActivity ||
        frameModule.topmost().android.currentActivity ||
        frameModule.topmost().android.activity;
var lastPress;

activity.onBackPressed = function() {
   topmost().goBack;
}
```

Comment: It works for Nativescript with javascript, but not for TypeScript + Angular